# Replacing marlett.ttf in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, fonts

The file not only seems to be locked and invisible in fonts directory but also right-click context menu is disabled for it... any ideas on how to make this file with normal attributes to do the job? or a tip in replacing it...

Tried

```
C:\Windows\Fonts>takeown /f marlett.ttf
```

SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "C:\Windows\Fonts\marlett.ttf" now owned by user

but no change seem to take effect...

it seems that I don't have ownership of fonts folder

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1076-fonts-delete.html) seems to be saying you need to go through the Control Panel or do it manually through the registry.

Comment: its a system font ... its not visible in control panel and deleting thru registry didnt do anything

Comment: got it to to work http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/78244-fonts-folder-permission.html

Comment: @Ely Great! Apologies that I couldn't be of more help.